# Exactly how to interpret the string filled in by std::getline(stream, string) function in C++

Tags: c++, std, ifstream

I am seeing something I can't understand.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
     
int main()
{

        std::ifstream someStream;
        someStream.open("testfile"); 
        std::string current_line;

        if ( someStream.good() )
        {

                while (std::getline(someStream, current_line))
                {

                        std::cout << current_line << "\n";
                        std::cout << std::string(std::begin(current_line), std::begin(current_line) + sizeof(long));
                        std::cout << "\n";

                }

        }

  return 0;

}
```

The `testfile` in the current directory has the format.

```
319528800,string1
319528801,string2
319528801,string3
319528802,string4
```

The problem I want to solve:

I want to extract the number before the first comma, on each line, and then make a map, using each of the numbers as keys. I am aware that the numbers are duplicate.
However I could not make the map, and it kept on inserting into itself only the first number.

The above code wants to print out the number before the first comma from each line. But it's not able to do so. However I am trying to print the string returned on every correct invocation of `std::getline` and I am able to print the current line.

EDIT : I was being overly asinine. I did overlook that `sizeof` or `std::size` is always a `const` for a predefined type.

Comment: `sizeof` is the size in memory of a type. It is not the number of characters needed to represent a number.

Comment: Why do you think `sizeof(long)` is going to find the comma? That's magical thinking, if you really think that is going to work. FYI `sizeof(long)` is a fixed value, usually either 4 or 8.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `std::ifstream someStream; someStream.open("testfile");` to `std::ifstream someStream("testfile");`. Also, `if (someStream.good()` is doubly redundant. Stream objects have an implicit conversion to `bool`, so `if (someStream)` is all that's needed. And even that isn't needed; if the stream isn't in a good state, the call to `getline` will fail and you'll get no output.

Comment: There's no reference to a comma anywhere in the code, so, that's important

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that looks for a comma in the current line

```
while (std::getline(someStream, current_line))
{
    std::cout << current_line << "\n";
    // get position of comma
    size_t pos = current_line.find(',');
    // get string before comma
    std::string tmp = current_line.substr(0, pos);
    // convert to long
    long num = stol(tmp);
```

Note this code assumes that there is a comma in the input, it will likely crash if there is not. You should always check your input data.

Comment: `std::stol(current_line)` works just fine; it stops parsing when it hits a character that can't be part of an integer, so there's no need for extracting that substring.

Answer (score 0):

You are overly complicating the parsing. In order to parse an entry from stream, you can do something along the lines

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream someStream("testfile");

    char sep;
    unsigned long num;
    std::string current_line;
    while (someStream >> num >> sep >> current_line) {
        if (sep != ',')
            break; // Bad separator
        std::cout << num << ", " << current_line << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @john True, the standard does not specify the size of integral types, only the ranges. I think "most often" would suffice.

Comment: seems reasonable

Comment: `std::stoi(current_line)` works just fine; it stops parsing when it hits a character that can't be part of an integer, so there's no need for extracting that substring.

Comment: `std::stoi` should probably be `std::stol`, since there's an implication that the code is supposed to create a `long`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks, I thought it would throw `std::invalid_argument`. Had to look it up.

Comment: Re: “had to look it up” — turn that into a habit.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
long value = std::stol(current_line);
```

`std::stol` skips leading whitespace, then parses the remaining text as an integer value. It stops when it hits a character that can't be part of an integer. So it will stop when it hits that `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer to make a struct that represents each line

```
struct input_line {
  long number;
  std::string str;
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, input_line& line) {
  char comma;
  if (in >> line.number >> comma >> line.str) {
    if (number < 0) throw std::runtime_error("invalid number ");
    if (comma != ',') throw std::runtime_error("missing comma");
    if (str.empty()) throw std::runtime_error("missing string");
  }
}
```

And then reading becomes trivial:

```
int main() {
  std::ifstream someStream("testfile"); 
  input_line line;
  while(someStream >> line)
    std::cout << line.number << ',' << line.str << '\n';
}
```

growing from this idea, we can actually use `istream_iterator` to read directly from the file into the map.

```
struct input_line {
  long number;
  std::string str;
  operator std::pair<long, std::string>() const &
  { return {number, str}; }
  operator std::pair<long, std::string>&&() &&
  { return {number, std::move(str)}; }
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, input_line& line) {
  char comma;
  if (in >> line.number >> comma >> line.str) {
    if (number < 0) throw std::runtime_error("invalid number ");
    if (comma != ',') throw std::runtime_error("missing comma");
    if (str.empty()) throw std::runtime_error("missing string");
  }
}

int main() {
  std::ifstream someStream("testfile"); 
  std::istream_iterator<input_line> first(someStream);
  std::map<long, std::string> map(first, {});

  for(auto&& pair : map) 
    std::cout << pair.first << ',' << pair.second << '\n';
}
```